# Can i get unmatched values from two texbox like this way?

Tags: c#

I can get values which are already matched. But i can't get unmatched values. How to make it work. Give me some advice guys

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String a = textBox3.Text;
            String b = textBox4.Text;
            string test = "";

            string[] titles1 = a.Split(new[] { ';', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] titles2 = b.Split(new[] { ';', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var duplicates = titles1.Distinct().Concat(titles2.Distinct()).GroupBy(title => title).Where(possibleDuplicates => possibleDuplicates.Skip(1).Any()).Select(duplicate => duplicate.First());

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string duplicate in duplicates)
            {
                //test = test + duplicate + "\r\n";
                System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("Missed call");

                table.Rows.Add(duplicate);
                Excel_read.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help for you

```
var result = titles1.Except(titles2).Concat(titles2.Except(titles1)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the differences you may use the following code (it is written on the fly, I don't say it is an performance-optimized algorithm, it is just an idea how your problem may be solved):

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 5};
var list2 = new List<int> {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};

var differences = list1.Where(v => !list2.Contains(v)).Concat(
                  list2.Where(v => !list1.Contains(v)));

// Or this compact version:
// var differences = list1.Except(list2).Concat(list2.Except(list1));
```

The differences IEnumerable will will contain the following result:

> {3, 4, 6}

Comment: The result will be {1,2,5,1,2,5}. Not that much of a difference.

Comment: @rs232, oh thanks for saying, I fixed the logic (I guess)

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "9"};
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8" };
List<string> list3 = list1;
list3.AddRange(list2);
list3 = list3.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```